# Does aws appsync have scan operations to scan dynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am building a serveless web app with aws amplify - graphql - dynamodb. I want to know what exactly a scan operation is in this context. For example, I have an User table and queries listUsers and getUser were generated from amplify schema. Are they scan operations or queries?

Thank you for your answers in advance as I could only find the definition of a scan operation but there aren't example for me to identify one when it comes to graphql.

Answer (score 2):

Amplify uses Filter Expressions which are a type of [Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.FilterExpression).

You can see this yourself by looking at the .vtl files that amplify generates and uploads to appsync.

They are located here: `amplify/#current-cloud-backend/api/[API NAME]/build/resolvers`

In that folder you can open up one of the `Query.list[Model].req.vtl`. Even if you are not familiar with [Velocity Template Language](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#velocity-template-language-vtl-an-introduction) you can still get the idea. You can see that it uses the expression `$util.transform.toDynamoDBFilterExpression`.

More info about that util  and then looking at the docs for [toDynamoDBFilterExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-util-reference.html).